# Install4j updater location in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, install4j

I want to automatically update my app with a script that launches the updater executable.

In Windows, the updater executable (updater.exe) is located by default in the .install4j directory.
In Mac OS X, I can't find it. The only updater file in the package is the .icns file, but there is no executable.

What is the updater executable in Mac OS X, and where is it located?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single bundle archive, there is no update executable. You can launch the updater with the code snippet that is provided by the integration wizard on the "launcher integration" tab of the updater configuration (on the Installer->Screens & Actions step).

Comment: OK. Is there another way to launch the updater? I want to launch it outside my app.

Comment: For a single bundle archive there is unfortunately no other way.